# Firefox displaying table-cell incorrectly (chrome working good)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-tables

I am designing site layout which consists of few divs. Whole site is in container. Everything under logo is construct and then I have content which is wrapped in content-wrapper. Content-wrapper has 2 childs: sidebar-wrapper and main-wrapper. I want to desing a few things in main-wrapper but it is not displaying correctly in firefox. Both main and sidebar are set to display table-cell but if I add img with text on right to main-wrapper then main-wrapper width changes and it is a bit wider then parent div (content wrapper). It happens in firefox and IE (chrome is working great). Here are some images shot with dev-tools enabled in firefox and chrome.

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

so is there any way to make table-cell fill parent width or to fix this problem somehow?

Comment: What happens if you display:block;

Comment: main-wrapper content moves down (under sidebar). But I want them to be next to each other.

Comment: do display block for both sidebar and main wrapper, put float:left; in sidebar and float:right; for main wrapper. Put clear:both; in content-wrapper. UPDATE: Float both left

Comment: or try, width:100%; in the main wrapper

Comment: hmm it is not working. It totaly broke my site because I also have footer and when I used your method then main-wrapper moved under sidebar and footer moved right to main wrapper and it also broke my sidebar menu

Comment: ummm, is the site a set width?

Comment: yes, container has set width of 1100px.

Comment: Well, that just leaves width, set width to 100%. If that doesn't work, set width to exact pixels, lets say side bar is 300px, make div container 800px

Comment: I cant use exact pixels because site us supposed to be responsive (using bootstrap and other functions).

Comment: if your content-wrapper is set to 1100px, its not going to be responsive to the screen size, therefore you can use exact pixels

Comment: well it is. Container (which is whole site excepting background has position relative and width: 1100px (+margin left and right are auto) and it is fully responsive.

Comment: try margin-right:<-width of your sidebar->; and if your sidebar has a width, what is it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32229/discussion-between-user2067005-and-horin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `table-layout:fixed;` on your wrapper div (the one that specifies `display: table;`)?

I had a similar problem, this property forces the table to be a fixed width instead of determined by its contents. By default the table columns are set to the width of the widest cell (with breakable content) in the row, in your case the image, hence the second column being too big :)

More information on `table-layout` can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Comment: But wouldn't this break the layout on a 'responsive' table?

Answer (score 1):

Place the below line in table class

```
table-layout: fixed;
```