# Firefox handles styles for <td> different than chromium-based browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

```css
.AA,
.AB,
.BC {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.AC,
.BA,
.BB {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}

.tableC {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="table_pictures">
  <h3> Lorem Ipsum dolor </h3>
  <table class="tableC">
    <tr>
      <td class="AA" rowspan="2"> Über zwei Zeilen
      </td>
      <td class="AB" rowspan="2"> Über zwei Zeilen
      </td>
      <td class="AC"> nur eine Zeile
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="BA"> nur eine Zeile
      </td>
      <td class="BB"> nur eine Zeile
      </td>
      <td class="BC" rowspan="2"> Über zwei Zeilen
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Firefox
[image]

Chrome based
[image]

I tried to style my site.html without changing anything in the html file. The table should look like the picture from the chrome-based browser. In Firefox the tables are complletly rendered different. But why? And what do i need to change?

I tried to use the answer from the following asked question but `table-layout:fixed;` didnt fixed it.

[Firefox displaying table-cell incorrectly (chrome working good)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258615/firefox-displaying-table-cell-incorrectly-chrome-working-good)

Comment: That structure makes little sense to begin with. If you use rowspan on some cells - then you should have a matching number of cells in the other columns.

Comment: @CBroe but how to do it without touching html? or wouldnt it possible by using firefox?

Comment: Why can't you tough that HTML? It is pretty nonsensical the way it is, so I'd say it _wants_ to be touched.

Comment: @CBroe technically sure i can do it. But i want to fix it only by using CSS

Comment: This should help [Setting a table's td height not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880222/setting-a-tables-td-height-not-working-in-firefox) I've tried it in FF and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could as well set the `tr` height to 75px

```css
.AA,
.AB,
.BC {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 150px;
}

.AC,
.BA,
.BB {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 75px;
}

.tableC {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

tr {
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table_pictures">
<h3> Lorem Ipsum dolor </h3>
<table class="tableC">
    <tr>
        <td class="AA" rowspan="2"> two rows
        </td>
        <td class="AB" rowspan="2"> two rows
        </td>
        <td class="AC"> only one row
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="BA"> only one row
        </td>
        <td class="BB"> only one row
        </td>
        <td class="BC" rowspan="2"> two rows
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Tested in Chrome and FF (and Safari)